# Pyhook Exit Program when a keybind is pressed

Tags: python, pyautogui, pyhook

I am trying to make an Emergency quit button but for some reason its not working.

Here is my code:

```
from pyhooked import Hook, KeyboardEvent, MouseEvent
import pyautogui, os, sys, time

print "to stop Press CONTROl + A\n"
Ammo = raw_input('Enter ammo amount: ')

def handle_events(args):
    if isinstance(args, KeyboardEvent):

        if args.current_key == 'A' and args.event_type == 'key down' and 'Lcontrol' in args.pressed_key:
            hk.exit()
        if args.current_key == 'B' and args.event_type == 'key down' and 'Lcontrol' in args.pressed_key:

            for i in range(int(Ammo)):
                (pyautogui.click(button='right'))
                (pyautogui.moveRel(2, 2, duration=0.01))
                (pyautogui.click(button='right'))
                (pyautogui.moveRel(-2, -2, duration=1.58))



hk = Hook()
hk.handler = handle_events
hk.hook()
```

It is designed so that I can run the program then go to the game and click my keybind connected to my program to run its action. Then it will do this action when I leave my computer saving me time.

But when I come back to my computer, I need to be able to take control of it again but my Close program keybind does not work.

The keybind to start the action is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> then when I want to exit the program I need the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> keybind to override the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> action and close the program.